# SQL Query help: co-workers and employees from one query

Tags: join

I have two tables defining users and user employments. The user table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fullName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

and the employments table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_employment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`employer_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
);
```

A user can employ users, but can also be employed. I need one query that can get all users that is a co-worker of a given user. I have tried with this query, but it only gives me employees for employer, or employer for employees:

```
    select u.id, u.username, u.fullName
      from user u
 left join user_employment e1 on e1.employee_id = u.id
 left join user_employment e2 on e2.employer_id = u.id
     where (e1.end >= NOW() or e1.end is NULL)
       and (e2.end >= NOW() or e2.end is NULL)
       and (e1.employee_id = <user id>
            or e1.employer_id = <user id>
            or e2.employee_id = <user id>
            or e2.employer_id = <user id>)
           and (e1.status = "confirmed"
                or e2.status = "confirmed")
               and u.id <> <user id>
  group by u.id;
```

If anything is unclear, please ask!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.id, u.username, u.fullName
from user u
join user_employment e1 on e1.employee_id = u.id
join user_employment e2 on e2.employer_id = e1.employer_id
where (e1.end >= NOW() or e1.end is NULL)
       and (e2.end >= NOW() or e2.end is NULL)
       and e2.employee_id = 2
       and e1.status = "confirmed"
       and e2.status = "confirmed"
       and u.id <> 2
group by u.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b13e6/4

Find the employer of a given user and then find all (other) employees of that employer. Do not use left joins unless you need them (you do not in this case).

Comment: I suppose "coworker" is defined as "having the same employer". If it is not so then please clarify that (and maybe add some example data and expected results).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very elegant and fast query that works great :) Just out of curiosity, is it possible to also get the employer?

Comment: @pusle Just add `e1.employer_id` to the selected columns. It should be the same in all rows unless the employee has two valid employers at the same time.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually yes, an employee can have multiple employers. I have a feeling I have done this much harder than it needs to be. Is it possible to solve with one query if there are multiple employers for one employee?

Comment: @pusle the query will still work the same, only in case the users will be coworkers "multiple times" (for two or more employers), only one (random) will be selected by `e1.employer_id` (or mysql might not allow the query if [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is set). you can either add that field to the GROUP BY (and get such user multiple times - once for each common employer) or use min(), max() or maybe group_concat() on  `e1.employer_id`  in the select - decide based on your needs.

Comment: A user only needs to show once, it is only when an employee has multiple employers that (s)he needs to see coworkers from all employers. So all is good, and I thank you very much for your help!